# how to display 2 month values in correct order using laravel

Tags: laravel-4

This is my table wys_attendence:

```
id   studid  adate  amonth  ayear  acls_id  attendence      
1    28      02     07      2015   10       1     
2    31      02     07      2015   10       0  
4    32      02     07      2015   10       1   
5    28      30     07      2015   10       0 
6    31      30     07      2015   10       1   
7    32      30     07      2015   10       1   
9    28      31     07      2015   10       1   
10   31      31     07      2015   10       1   
11   32      31     07      2015   10       1   
13   28      06     08      2015   10       1   
14   31      06     08      2015   10       0   
15   32      06     08      2015   10       1   
17   28      07     08      2015   10       0   
18   31      07     08      2015   10       1   
19   32      07     08      2015   10       1   
21   28      08     08      2015   10       1   
22   31      08     08      2015   10       1   
23   32      08     08      2015   10       0   
24   28      12     08      2015   10       1   
25   31      12     08      2015   10       1   
26   32      12     08      2015   10       0
```

I want to check if values between the t_adates is in the table, and to display values from between the t_adates

if I am select `1/07/2015 to 31/08/0215`.

The output I get is incorrect. This is what I get:

```
  studid  2/07/2015  06/08/2015 07/08/2015  08/08/2015 30/07/205 31/07/2015 
  28     1              1         0            1          0          1          
  31     0              0         1            1          1          1           
  32     1              1         1            0          1          1
```

not display  values are incorrect order

But I want it like this:

```
studid  2/07/2015  30/07/205 31/07/2015 06/08/2015 07/08/2015  08/08/2015
  28     1            0          1           1         0            1
  31     0            1          1           0         1            1
  32     1            1          1           1         1            0
```

my controller code is here

```
       `$startdate_exploded = explode("/",Input::get('curdate'));          
        $enddate_exploded = explode("/",Input::get('enddate'));                 
        $attendence_tbl = WysAttendancename::where('cls_id',$id)->first();
        $wys_attendence_table = $attendence_tbl->attendance_name;
        $attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                     ->whereBetween('adate', array($startdate_exploded[0], $enddate_exploded[0]))
                     ->whereBetween('amonth', array($startdate_exploded[1], $enddate_exploded[1]))
                     ->whereBetween('ayear', array($startdate_exploded[2], $enddate_exploded[2]))
                     ->groupBy('adate')
                     ->get();
        $stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                    ->whereBetween('adate', array($startdate_exploded[0], $enddate_exploded[0]))
                    ->whereBetween('amonth', array($startdate_exploded[1], $enddate_exploded[1]))
                    ->whereBetween('ayear', array($startdate_exploded[2], $enddate_exploded[2]))    
                    ->get();`
```

my view.blade.php is

```
 `<td>Student Name</td>
                     @foreach($attendance as $attendances)
                    <td><font size="-1">{{$attendances->adate}}-{{$attendances->amonth}}-{{$attendances->ayear}}</font></td>
                    @endforeach
                  </tr>
                  @foreach($students as $student)
                  @if($student->studcls == $id)
                  <tr>   
                    <td>{{$student->studname}}</td>
                  @foreach($stud_attend as $stud_attends)
                  @if($student->id == $stud_attends->studid)  
                  @if($stud_attends->attendence == 1)
                  <td><font color="green" size="3">p</font></td>
                  @elseif($stud_attends->attendence == 0)
                  <td><font color="red" size="3">a</font></td>   
                  @endif
                  @endif
                  @endforeach
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                  @endforeach`
```

How can I modify my query to achieve the above result as well as check all dates (01/07/2015 to 31/08/2015 ) are in the database or not if in database then day display only once and display all details in from database?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group records by date then use groupBy() as explained on http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects

```
$attendance = DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
->where('t_amonth', $amonth)
->where('t_ayear',$ayear)
->groupBy('t_adate')
->get();
```